# Statically linked executable with dynamic loading

Tags: static-libraries, static-linking, dynamic-linking, dynamic-loading, object-code

I'm not sure if it makes sense or not, but is it possible to have a statically linked executable + dynamic loading ?

In other words: at compile/linking time an object code is statically linked against libraries, however at runtime the loading in memory of the relevant code from libraries is postponed until the relevant library's functions are actually called/invoked from the executable.

Does it makes sense ? Thank you.

Edit: to me it seems Dynamic Linking actually requires Dynamic Loading.

Comment: yes it is posssible

Comment: What you say sounds possible, but I am not sure what "loading in memory" refers to, in this context. The layout is more important here, as the MMU loads blocks from your binary.

You can try the idea from APE. Read the last paragraph from https://justine.lol/cosmo3/, section "Portability and Performance (Pick Two)"

Comment: The point puzzling me is that library's function addresses are actually known since the main object code has been statically linked. Therefore the dynamic loader must load the library's function code (when called the first time) at those specific addresses in the process's virtual address space. Right ?

Comment: Not if you have ASLR enabled, for example. The loading is already done lazily, through the GOT. I think what you want is already being the standard way to do it. You can read up more on the GOT, https://ctf101.org/binary-exploitation/what-is-the-got/ and related concepts.

Comment: Ah ok, so if ASLR is enabled, even in the case of statically linked executable the addresses of library's functions are not resolved at linking time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In other words: at compile/linking time an object code is statically linked against libraries, however at runtime the loading in memory of the relevant code from libraries is postponed until the relevant library's functions are actually called/invoked from the executable.

This question is somewhat ambiguous and depends on what *exactly* you mean by "loading in memory".

Let's consider execution of a fully-statically linked `./a.out` ELF binary on Linux.

Such a binary has one or more `PT_LOAD` segments, which tell the kernel how to [mmap](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) that binary into memory.

In one sense, the entire code of the binary (including all library code) is loaded into memory (e.g., that code appears in `/proc/self/maps`) before the first instruction from `./a.out` even runs.

However, with [demand paging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demand_paging), *none* of that code is actually occupying any physical RAM. When you access the first instruction (at the `_start` symbol) of `./a.out`, there is a [page fault](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_fault), and the OS loads the page containing that instruction is *actually* loaded into physical memory and restarts the instruction, which causes it to finally be executed.

Likewise, when you call some library function, there is (possibly) another page fault, and the OS loads the code for the called library function.

(Aside: above behavior could be modified by a call to [mlock](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mlock.2.html) or `mlockall`).

---

Another possible interpretation of your question is "is it possible to `mmap` the library code *only* when the library function is called?".

In this interpretation, the library code does not appear in the process's address space until called.

This is quite possible to do: you just need to replace the actual code for the `library_function` with a "stub". When that stub is called, it would perform the necessary `mmap` to "actually load" the library code into memory (if that hasn't been done already) and then jump to the "actual" `library_function`.

---

The only reason to perform the second (more complicated) dance (that I can think of) is if your OS lacks demand paging (which probably means that it doesn't support paging *at all*).

There is probably some embedded OS out there which does do that.

Comment: Yes, the second interpretation is what I meant. But in case of _statically linked executable_ there is no place for "stubs", hence I am not sure if the concept of dynamic loading applies to it as well.

Comment: @CarloC I don't understand what you mean by "there is no place for stubs" -- the place is in the main executable, and if you can place the actual implementation of the `library_function`, then you can also place the "stub" there (the "stub" would usually be shorter" than the actual implementation).

Comment: Yes, but in this case we're actually talking about dynamic linking and not only dynamic loading (since actual function's addresses have to be resolved at loading/run time).

Comment: @CarloC Yes, effectively if you want the code to appear in the address space dynamically, then you are (re-inventing) dynamic loading.

Comment: Just to be clear: to me a statically linked executable contains inside it all the code from the linked libraries. In other words I believe the concept of dynamic loading makes sense _only_ in the context of dynamic linking.

Comment: Does it exist an example of dynamic loading only (i.e. no dynamic linking) under linux ?

Comment: @CarloC "dynamic loading only (i.e. no dynamic linking)" -- yes, nearly all just-in-time compilers work that way. https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2013/11/05/how-to-jit-an-introduction